If we take output across c​ in a CE amplifier instead of across collector and emitter or (ground). Would it blow up my circuit?
In a common-emitter amplifier, the output across the collector and emitter (or ground) shows a 180° phase shift relative to the input. However, if the output is taken across the collector resistor (Rc), there won't be a 180° phase shift. This is because an increase in (Ib) increases (Ic), which increases the voltage drop across (Rc). The voltage across (Rc) directly follows the input signal's phase, as it increases with (Ic). So, why the output is not taken across Rc instead of taking across the collector and emitter or ground?

Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

"why the output is not taken across..." This question is more about decisions made in electrical engineering rather than physics.

A common emitter transistor is usually part of a larger circuit, and the rest of the circuit will usually expect signals to be relative to ground. If you have only a single CE transistor then yes you could take the output across the collector resistor, but even then you need to be very sure that whatever you are connecting it to does not share a common ground with your CE circuit. Getting this wrong usually results in smoke, or if you're very lucky a loud bang.
